# About Navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add uinavigation controller in a view based application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398151/how-to-add-uinavigation-controller-in-a-view-based-application)

I am new user of objective c.....so I have not more idea about objective c,so I want to know that How we add navigation controller to the view based application ?.....

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a new project in Xcode and choose the Master-Detail Application template, then examine the automatically generated code, especially in the AppDelegate the method `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. You will see how a new `UINavigationController` is created, another `UIViewController` is created and added to the `UINavigationController` and then the `UINavigationController` is set as `rootViewController` of the window.

Answer (score 0):

// Add Navigation controller on app delgete window.

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil]];

[Window addSubView: navigationController];

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController *aViewController = ...
//you need to allocate your view controller object
UINavigationController *newController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aViewController];

[self presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES];

//you need to release the controller
[newController release];

Comment: see himanshu, navigation controller behaves like a array it contains all the view controller to it's index.you can easily accessed as you did in case of array.......